# Strange CakePHP message: View file is missing

Tags: cakephp

I am developing a website in CakePHP.
When I go one page back / forward (arrow in your browser) I get the following:

```
{
    "code": 500,
    "url": "\urlToWebisite/uploads\/view\/31",
    "name": "View file &quot;urlToWebisite\\app\\View\\Uploads\\json\\view.ctp&quot; is missing."
}
```

The whole page is white and this is the only thing I see...

My error log says:

```
2014-04-12 22:10:27 Error: [MissingViewException] View file "C:\url\app\View\Users\json\view.ctp" is missing.
Exception Attributes: array (
  'file' => 'C:\\url\\app\\View\\Users\\json\\view.ctp',
)
Request URL: /url/users/view/1
Stack Trace:
#0 C:\url\lib\Cake\View\JsonView.php(107): View->_getViewFileName(NULL)
#1 C:\url\lib\Cake\Controller\Controller.php(952): JsonView->render(NULL, NULL)
#2 C:\url\lib\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php(192): Controller->render()
#3 C:\url\lib\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php(160): Dispatcher->_invoke(Object(UsersController), Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#4 C:\url\app\webroot\index.php(108): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#5 {main}
```

Posting my appController won't be necessary: It's only loading models and settings variables for view.

When I reload the page, it loads perfect.

I don't know where to search to the solution. So, please give me some hints!

If I didn't place enough information, please comment ;)

Greetzz

Comment: What happens when you reload the page? Sometimes I get that kind of error when I upload the file via FTP and reload while the file's being written. It gets fixed when I re-upload.

Comment: check your `app/tmp/logs/error.php` file - You'll need to show some relevant application code if you want some help.

Comment: @schnauss: I am working in Xampp. I tested it on a server, but still got the error. When I reload the page shows normally.

Comment: @AD7six Sorry, got the wrong error. Here's the good one: 2014-04-12 23:06:10 Error: [MissingViewException] View file "C:\url\app\View\Uploads\json\view.ctp" is missing.
Exception Attributes: array (
  'file' => 'C:\\url\\app\\View\\Uploads\\json\\view.ctp',
)
Request URL: /url/uploads/view/31
Stack Trace:
#0 C:\url\lib\Cake\View\JsonView.php(107): View->_getViewFileName(NULL)
#1 C:\url\lib\Cake\Controller\Controller.php(952): JsonView->render(NULL, NULL)
#2 C:\url\lib\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php(192): Controller->render()

Comment: Have you tried creating a view.ctp? What does your controller code look like? I've run into similar problems in the past.

Comment: @schnauss: well, as far as I know I don't use an `C:\url\app\View\Uploads\json\view.ctp`... I have never asked for that page ;) My controllercode is simple: `$data = $this->Upload->find('all'); $this->set('uploads', $data);` Don't think thats the problem....

Comment: @AD7six: Well, I have to learn! Is this better?

Comment: It's better but only just: Your users controller is still missing; there's no request object info (no means to say why it's detected as a json request).

Comment: @AD7six: Well, that's my problem to! I don't even know! And a Controller is irrelevant information because it is on every page!

Comment: @Bob: The way your controller is set up right now, it's expecting you to generate the JSON with a view file. It's not finding one, and so it's generating an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution... I disabled all `.js` files and the problem was gone... Now going to find the wrong `.js` file.

This code:

```
$( '#bottom-panel .twitter-feed' ).each(function(){
        $(this).uouTwitterFeed();
    });
```

Costed me 2 hours :)

Comment: I am having same issue. There is no function called uouTwitterFeed(). but showing twitter feeds on the site. Can you explain where was the error?